How to upgrade React 16.12 and Node 14.5 to the latest versions in a large-scale project
I'm currently working on a large-scale project that uses React 16.12 and Node 14.5, and I would like to upgrade both to their latest versions. I've noticed that there have been significant changes and improvements in both React and Node.js since the versions I'm using, and I want to ensure my project takes advantage of these updates.
Could someone guide me through the process of upgrading both React and Node.js?
Specifically, I am looking for advice on:
1. Best practices for upgrading React:

What are the steps to upgrade React from 16.12 to the latest version?
Are there any breaking changes or deprecations I should be aware of?
How can I update my project dependencies accordingly?

2. Best practices for upgrading Node.js:

How can I safely upgrade Node.js from 14.5 to the latest version?
What are the potential issues I might encounter during this upgrade?
Are there any tools or commands that can help streamline this process?

3. General tips:

How can I test my project thoroughly after the upgrades to ensure nothing is broken?
Any recommended resources or documentation for further reading on these upgrades?

Here is my current package.json for reference:
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.10",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=13.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/charts": "^1.4.2",
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.0.2",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.1.0",
    "@google/model-viewer": "^1.6.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
    "@use-it/event-listener": "^0.1.6",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.19.0",
    "antd": "^4.10.0",
    "array-move": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "blueimp-load-image": "^5.14.0",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^3.0.3",
    "canvas2pdf": "^1.0.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "colorette": "^1.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.25.5",
    "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "customize-cra": "^0.9.1",
    "dom-to-image-more": "^2.8.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "exif-js": "^2.3.0",
    "fabric": "^4.3.0",
    "fabric-webpack": "^1.6.0-rc.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "highcharts": "^8.1.2",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^2.2.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "is-touch-device": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jszip": "^3.7.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.39",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.5.207",
    "rc-color-picker": "^1.2.6",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
    "react-butterfiles": "^1.3.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.8.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.2",
    "react-cognito": "^1.5.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-csv": "^1.1.2",
    "react-data-export": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dnd": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.5",
    "react-fabricjs": "^0.1.6",
    "react-image-magnifiers": "^1.4.0",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-image-zoom": "^1.3.1",
    "react-mentions": "^4.4.10",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-photo-collage": "^1.0.7",
    "react-player": "^2.7.2",
    "react-promise-tracker": "^2.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-three-fiber": "^4.2.20",
    "react-to-pdf": "0.0.14",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.5",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.15",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^1.6.1",
    "reactjs-percentage-circle": "^1.0.0",
    "reactour": "^1.18.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-observable": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "round-slider": "^1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "three": "^0.113.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-app-rewired build",
    "build:staging": "set REACT_APP_ENV=staging && react-app-rewired build",
    "deploy": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://my-project --acl public-read",
    "deploy-dev": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://my-project-dev-dev --acl public-read",
    "invalidate-dev": "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <DistID> --paths \"/*\"",
    "invalidate": "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <DistID> --paths \"/*\"",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "release": "standard-version",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "less": "^3.13.1",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "standard-version": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


Be prepared for work
I would expect quite a bit of work for updating your setup, just because of the sheer amount of dependencies. React is probably the lesser problem here.
There will be many errors to fix.
It even might happen that one or the other package is impossible to update, and has to be removed or replaced. (But maybe you are lucky.)
Update process
(you probably know npm outdated or yarn outdated)
(1)
I would update node.js first, maybe to version 18 (instead of 20), because it's a bit more likely that most packages are compatible. But I would generally not try to downgrade node.js any further just to make some old package happy. And at the end I would still try node 20 as well.
I wouldn't expect problems with updating node.js itself, only with old packages requiring old node versions.
Some packages will probably not work with the new node.js version, but also some updated packages will probably not work with the old node.js version, so you have this problem anyway, so better use the newer one.
(2)
I would identify packages that are probably easy to update, and/or have only a minor version change, and update them first. If they work, then they are out of the way. Otherwise I would undo that update for now (to try it later with more effort).
(3)
Then I would try to update packages where I expect more significant changes, and generally update packages "less careful", while being prepared undo specific updates, mainly to see which kind of errors I will have to deal with. Especially, some packages might have huge breaking changes, but might be relatively quick and easy to fix.
If there are exceptionally hard problems (like version conflicts between packages), I would decide individually. Some packages might need to be kept on specific versions instead of the latest one, or (as mentioned above) need to be replaced completely.
(4)
Then, knowing what to expect, I would update individual packages in a more organized way. There will probably be errors. Ideally you now always can plan and predict which errors will come up or will be solved, but there will probably also still be surprises.
Specific packages
I don't know most of your dependencies, but here some of my expecations:
Babel/Webpack: I would expect fundamental changes regarding all babel- and webpack-related packages (including it's loaders, config files, API, ...). That's probably all solvable, but takes time to research, and nothing else will work before this is fixed.
React: There is the option to update first to React v17, and later to React v18, but I'm not sure if that makes anything easier. Note that all of the errors have to be fixed anyway, sooner or later. I would probably try React v18 right away, and see what happens.
See React v17.0 and How to Upgrade to React 18
linters: I would expect that static code analysers (eslint) will find a lot more errors than before, which might take days to fix (depends on how strict and or modern you wrote your code already). If it's only stricter rules (and not fundamental implementation), then maybe you can keep that update for later, or update it but not yet to the latest version.
state: I would be a bit cautious about the state management libraries (redux related packages, rxjs, ...). E.g. I know there were significant changes in redux, but I'm not sure how well the old code will still work (may or may not).
others: There are some packages that look like they might make trouble, but I can't go into details for all of them.
Recently I've noticed that some npm packages like to migrate from CJS to ESM, which can cause trouble (I mean generally, I don't know about yours). In case of trouble, maybe try the last CJS version for now.
